# How to add a value to future values?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

So I am quite new to SQL so please be gentle.

I am using Oracle Apex to generate a bar chart showing the amount of storage used in a particular database over the last 12 months.  In this chart I am trying to add an additional feature where the chart will show (via a line) how much storage will likely be used on a fortnightly basis over the course of the next three months.

I have created a PL/SQL function (GET_PREDICTED_VALUE) which generates the anticipated value I require, but I am having trouble using that value to show the predicted trend.  If the generated anticipated value is positive, that’s how much more storage is needed.  If the anticipated value is negative, that’s how much less storage is needed (the arguments sent into this function are how many days ago do I want to draw the ‘storage used’ values.  30 will be 30 days ago, 150 is 150 days ago etc).

What I would like to do is use this anticipated value and add it to the last ‘current storage used’ value recorded in the database.  I would like the anticipated value to be continually added so that a future trend can be observed.

For example, if the last ‘current storage used’ value saved in the database is 50, and the anticipated value is 3, then the value for the immediate future date should be 53.  And the next future value should be 56, and the next should be 59, and so on up to three months ahead.

This is the code I have so far, and it works insofar that the chart I need does get generated and the trend line runs across the previous year and then the future three months.  But for the future three months, I am only able to get the trend line to represent the anticipated value, not the value continually added E.g again, if the anticipated value is 3, my trend line shows 3 across all future dates.

```
WITH src AS
(
    SELECT GET_PREDICTED_VALUE(1, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180) AS predictedValue FROM DUAL
),
mydays as 
(
    select level mylevel, 
           sysdate + level as futureDate 
    from dual
    connect by level <= 90
),
future_values as 
(
    SELECT MAX(src.predictedValue)                     AS "ASM Used", 
           TO_CHAR(TRUNC(futureDate,'IW') ,'DD/MM/YY') AS "Capture Date", 
           TRUNC(futureDate,'IW')                      AS capture_date_order
    FROM mydays
    CROSS JOIN src
    GROUP BY TRUNC(futureDate,'IW')
    ORDER BY TRUNC(futureDate,'IW')
),
SRC_back AS
(
    SELECT TRUNC(capture_date,'IW')                    AS week, 
           database_name, 
           MAX((os_usable_total_mb-os_usable_free_mb)) AS ASMUsed
    FROM tablespace_used
    WHERE capture_date >= (SYSDATE - 360)
    GROUP BY TRUNC(capture_date,'IW'), database_name, tablespace_name
),
back_values as 
(
    SELECT /*+ parallel(a, 8)  */
           TO_CHAR(week,'DD/MM/YY')         AS "Capture Date", 
           week                             AS capture_date_order, 
           ROUND( MAX(ASMUsed/1024/1024 ) ) AS "ASM Used"
    FROM src_back a
    WHERE week >= (SYSDATE - 360)
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(week,'DD/MM/YY'), week
    ORDER BY 2
)
select "Capture Date", capture_date_order,  "ASM Used" from back_values
union 
select  "Capture Date", capture_date_order,  "ASM Used" from future_values
order by 2
```

I hope my explanation is clear, and if anyone could let me know what I have to do to get my trend line running the way I need?

(This is an image of how my chart looks so far):
[image]

Comment: Your function will only return a single value; when you cross join it with mydays, the same value will merely be repeated for each day. I don't understand how the six parameters are supposed to work in that function - I would have expected the function to take a single parameter (a number of days offset) and call it multiple times (e.g. from within your `mydays` subquery).

Comment: HI.  That's true.  My function does return a single value.  I was wondering if there was a way to repeatedly add that value to dates in the future so that I could see whether my trend line increase or decreases.  I'm not sure how to do that.  The reason I have multiple arguments for the function is so that the user can decide whether they want the offsets to be consistent or not.

Comment: Repeatedly add - as in, multiplication?

Comment: As in, let's take for example the last field of my table is dated today (25/7/19) and the amount of storage used is 50 units, and my function calculates a value of 3.  My chart should then show one week in the future, the anticipated storage to be used will be 53.  Two weeks in the future should show 56.  Three weeks in the future should show 59.  And so on up to a maximum of twelve weeks in the future (with the predicted value twelve weeks in the future being 86).  Is there a way to do that in my query?

Comment: If your function returns 3, why not multiply it be level to get 3, 6, 9, 12, etc.

Comment: Since I basically need the value to be repeatedly added to the last recorded value, would you per chance know how to modify my above query to get the required outcome?

Comment: Something like: `with mydays as (select level * GET_PREDICTED_VALUE(1) as predictedValue, sysdate + level as futureDate from dual connect by level <= 90)`, and remove the `src` subquery. Then for future days: `SELECT MAX(mydays.predictedValue)                     AS "ASM Used", ... FROM mydays`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: You're new here. "did not work" is not an error message. If you want more help you need to do a little bit of work. Gather data, put together a test case that clearly shows *inputs* and expected *outputs*. Show what you've tried so far, and what the results were. In other words, I don't have a crystal ball and can't see your screen.

Comment: I meant that when I tried your suggestion, the trendline ran across the bottom of the chart, and when it ran to the period covering the future, the line skyrocketed diagonally to the top of the chart. I have tried a variety of ways to get the results I require including controlling the inputs and outputs.  I've added an image of my chart to my original question to show the best I've managed to get so far if that helps. The line runs horizontally across the future period when it should be rising or falling according to the predicted value.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. What I mean is, if you want more help, you need to *show your work* - actually provide a test case which includes inputs, outputs, and expected outputs. Best of luck.